# Which is the default/prefered compiler in F18?

Tags: fedora

I am having trouble trouble finding an installed by default compiler on Fedora18. *Where is it?*

If strangely no compiler is included in the core distribution, is there a preferred compiler for casual users, needing to compile a package from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native C compiler (meaning, the compiler used to compile the system) on all GNU/Linux systems including any version of fedora is `gcc`.

It is not necessarily installed by default, however, because a *pre-compiled* (binary distro) system does not need one to install or function.

`yum install gcc` should get you what you are after.  If you are building from source tarballs put together with autotools ("configure, make, install"), you'll also want `tar` and `make`, obviously.

So at minimum, either as root or sudo:

```
yum install gcc tar make
```

A lot of packages will require more than this; eg. if there are C++ parts, you'd also need a C++ compiler (on fedora, the `gcc-c++` package).

Thanks to jordanm for pointing out a group install:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Again, keep in mind it is not really possible to cover everything that could possibly be needed for any package, but hopefully the configure script provides helpful clues when something is missing.

Comment: Are there any other packages, commonly required when compiling packages source code: maketool, Doxygen, binutils, etc.? A command-line of the type `su -c "yum install essential packages for native toolchain"` would be quite helpful!

Comment: There may be but I'll admit ignorance.  You probably want make and tar (I added a note about that) but, beyond whatever particular -dev packages, I think that's it.  The `autoconf` package is used to *create* configure scripts, but they should *run* on their own.  They like to see various things from coreutils (gawk, etc) but those should be there already.

Comment: @vorac - You want `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`